# Custom JWplayer Control bar

Tags: html, css, jwplayer

Here is JWPlayer default control bar:
[image]

Can we custom control bar in JWPLayer as below:

[image]

I mean the color and removing/arranging some elements on it such as jw-text-elapsed, jw-text-duration...

```js
var playerInstance = jwplayer("divplayer"); playerInstance.setup({
  file:'//video.radioradicale.it:1935/store-86/_definst_/mp4:2015/01/MQ781257.mp4/playlist.m3u8',
  width:544, height: 306,
});
```

```css
.jw-knob {
    background-color: #ee3137 !important;
}
.jw-text-elapsed, .jw-icon-rewind {
  display: none;
}

.jw-icon-playback {
    background-color: #ee3137 !important;
    border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<title>JWPlayer 7 controlbar position</title>
  <script src="//ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.10.7/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";</script>
</head>
<body class="playerpage">
  <div id='divplayer'></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

As above snippet, how we can decrease colored circle size. And also how we can place jw-text-elapsed and jw-text-duration side by side as in the photo (0.00/1.24).

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: my previous answer in the other question works? :-)

Comment: Yes, it works in that case but in my code it's complex more than that and I still cant apply your way. However, I found a simple way to fix that as I commented.
Anyway, voted/marked it as accepted answer. Thanks,

Comment: I understand, so I think that you need to build your custom skin, read this: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_creating/ in 'Advanced Skinning' section. You can modify .less premade skin and then rebuilding it